# EOSIO retrieve 12 char name from blockchain api

Tags: eosjs

Hello is there any function available from which we can retrieve 12 char name by giving private key ?
or you can say api function or eos library for import eos account

Answer (score 2):

**First of all: Never publish your private key, don't make it public, don't paste it to any api's or so, the only place to paste it is your wallet.**

Assuming you are speaking about the **public key** of a specific account, there's the [get_accounts_by_authorizers](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/chain_api_plugin/api-reference/index#operation/get_accounts_by_authorizers)-endpoint provided by the chain-api.
Note that it's only available if `enable-account-queries` is set to true in your nodeos-config.

Comment: please mark answers solving your problems as correct, for any future users.

Comment: actullay i want to get my 12 char name from public key EOS........12a from this so please let me how to do that?

Comment: As said above, use the get_accounts_by_authorizers-endpoint in a node where it's enabled.